# Passing a typedef enum as a parameter in c throwing error

Tags: c, types, syntax, enums, casting

I'm programming in a cortex m3 for the LPC1343 microcontroller. When I compile my code I get an error in the line `SetLed((eLeds_t *)h1, false);` it says `Error[Pe018]: expected a ")"` as if this the cast that I do wasn't good enough I guess.

Follows the enum type def declaration and the :

```
#ifndef _LEDS_h
#define _LEDS_h

#ifndef bool
typedef unsigned char bool;
# define true 1;
# define false 0;
#endif // ifndef bool

enum eLeds
{
    noled, p1l, p1r, p2l, p2r, h1, h2
};
typedef enum eLeds eLeds_t;

void SetLed(eLeds_t led, bool action)
{
    switch (led)
    {
    case p1l:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT2, 5, action);
        break;

    case p1r:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT2, 8, action);
        break;

    case p2l:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT0, 9, action);
        break;

    case p2r:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT0, 8, action);
        break;

    case h1:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT0, 5, action);
        break;

    case h2:
        GPIOSetValue(PORT0, 7, action);
        break;
    }
}

void leds_init(void)
{
    GPIOSetDir(PORT2, 5, 1); // p1l
    GPIOSetDir(PORT2, 8, 1); // p1r
    GPIOSetDir(PORT0, 9, 1); // p2l
    GPIOSetDir(PORT0, 8, 1); // p2r

    GPIOSetDir(PORT0, 5, 1); // h1
    GPIOSetDir(PORT0, 7, 1); // h2

    LPC_IOCON->PIO2_5 &= ~0x07;
    LPC_IOCON->PIO2_8 &= ~0x07;
    LPC_IOCON->PIO0_9 &= ~0x07;
    LPC_IOCON->PIO0_8 &= ~0x07;

    LPC_IOCON->PIO0_5 &= ~0x07;
    LPC_IOCON->PIO0_7 &= ~0x07;

    eLeds_t value = h1;
    SetLed(&value, false);
}

#endif // ifndef _LEDS_h
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you casting the enum value to a pointer?

Comment: You can declare a local of type eLeds_t and assign that `h1`. You can pass reference of that variable to function. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: The only warning I get is that the `switch()` doesn't handle the `noled` case.

Comment: The real code probably has a missing `;` somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure `false` and `bool` are valid with your compiler?

Comment: I've made the bool definition by my self, see the new code above.

Comment: Well, nobody else is going to be able to compile your code since it has a bunch of external dependencies. When I grabbed it before you edited it to make it harder for others to compile I just changed bool to int and passed 0 and it worked fine in GCC.  Surely you can make a simple example that doesn't require anything outside itself. That may help you find the problem yourself.

Comment: I think it's the compiler fault I think it's proprietary from IAR.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the enum (probably a value like 0, 1, 2...) to a pointer and then the method you pass that to expects to dereference the pointer and use what it is pointing at? Even if the passing syntax was right (and it does look syntactically ok - if not sensible), it will invoke undefined behavior on the dereference.

This will work:

```
void leds_init(void)
{
    eLeds_t   value = h1;
    SetLed(&value, false);
}
```

The fact that all of this is in a .h is WRONG. If you include it from multiple places your going to have multiply defined symbols.

Your handling of bool is WRONG. `#ifndef bool` will only pick up if bool has been hash defined. It won't pick up a typedef-ed bool. Find out what the compiler has and use that. In C TRUE and FALSE are normally defined (stdio.h?) - use those. Or better yet not a bool. Why not an action enum "PERFORM_ACTION" and "SKIP_ACTION"? That way you don't need to remember what that `bool` was supposed to be...

Comment: This doesn't explain why he's getting a syntax error. There's probably a missing `;` in his real code.

Comment: John I've just tried and it didn't work, I've checked for missing semicolons as well and it's all there.

Comment: The error is not simple casting stuff then. Perhaps there is a problem earlier in the file (or in one of the includes)? Is `h1` defined as something else? From the screenshot to the snippet there is code missing - the issue is probably in there somewhere.

Comment: That's in a header file? This is probably your first mistake. You're also going to have to look where it is included from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147996/discussion-between-rinaldi-segecin-and-john3136).

Comment: John I've just spited the header to a c file and I'm still getting the same error. I think it's a compiler issue and I'll use number instead. But thanks everyone.